# Map api key is not loading map on android phone

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, api-key

I am trying to put multiple coordinates on a single map. 
I searched and knows that it required `map API key` as show on map view. but after following all instructions on [`https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys`](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys) I generate map API key, but its not working. This key is not loading map showing on check box.

Logcat:-

```
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520): IOException processing: 26
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
03-02 14:57:30.855: W/System.err(20520):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: what is the problem you encounter? show your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code and also clarify that which Google Map library are you using As v1 has been deprecated and you should go for GoogleMaps V2, which requires the SH1 key to generate the API key from Google maps API console.

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is you are running app in debug mode and the api key is for the keystore create the apk of the project install that and then try to run it If you have done everything else correct you should be able to see the map.

also [This tutorial for obtaining Key is amazing](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is nice, but it refers to an MD5 hash. Google does not use an MD5 hash for API key generation, they use an SHA-1 hash. This tutorial worked well for me....

[Sue Smith's Tutorial at mobile tuts+](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/)